# A dialogue box appears to save a file every time the session code is run?

Tags: java, eclipse, session, servlets, tracking

I wrote a session code to track a session in eclipse. Instead of displaying in the web page the session id gets save as a file in my computer and every time the code is run the dialogue box to save file keeps appearing

i don't really know what is the issue. gooogled it but can't find anything related

here is my code:

```java
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class SessionTrack
     */
    public class SessionTrack extends HttpServlet {

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {        
            response.setContentType("html/text");

            try {
                PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                pw.println("<html><body>");
                pw.println(session.getId());
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(2*60);

                if(session.isNew()) {
                    pw.println("Welcome new user");
                    //System.out.println("asd");

                }
                else {
                    pw.println("Welcome back user");
                    pw.println("</html></body>");
                    pw.close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: The content type should be `text/html`, not `html/text`.

Comment: Don't forget the setMaxInactiveInterval is in seconds, so you renew the session every 2 minutes

Comment: correction of text/html worked for me thanks @RealSkeptic